# Should there be an "Identify-this-documentary" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, identify

Identification questions looking for a documentary end up using some combination of [identify-this-movie](/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie), [identify-this-tv-show](/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show), [documentary](/questions/tagged/documentary) and few other tags giving additional information about the documentary.

As the number of documentary identification questions are gradually [increasing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=documentary%20is%3Aquestion) I think now it is a good time to create a a tag [identify-this-documentary](/questions/tagged/identify-this-documentary) for better cataloging/indexing purpose.

I didn't want to create it and start tagging the relevant questions immediately without discussing.

Thoughts?

Comment: By the way, [this](http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentify-this-*%5D+documentary+is%3Aquestion) was the search query you probably wanted to use.

Comment: Thanks for that query and your explanation.

Comment: Still a good question, though.  I was actually wondering the same thing, but, I forgot to ask about it in chat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, there shouldn't.

Documentary is less of a medium than rather a genre or style. Documentaries can very well be either movies or TV-shows, which are the media that we separate ID questions into. So in this case the working procedure is to tag the question with an appropriate ID tag ([identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) or [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show)), depending what it is. And then add the [documentary](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentary) tag on top of it, like we do with e.g. [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) or [horror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) (we don't have an [identify-this-animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-animation) tag).

I understand that this approach has its disadvantages, too. For example the distinction between movies and TV-shows might not even be necessary and it also requires additional tags as helpers that otherwise wouldn't make too much sense of their own. But it's the currently existing tagging procedure for ID questions and as long as that doesn't get a major overhaul, introducing an [identify-this-documentary](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-documentary) tag will be a huge inconsistency in this approach.